# Que tipo de coordenações possui o período "Ele deixou entrar o garçom e não o viu esconder alguns talheres, apesar de ser um administrador"?

Tags: orações-subordinadas, análise-sintática

Na verdade o período em questão é um pouco maior. Trata-se de uma questão de prova de concurso público já realizado. (Órgão: SEDUC-AM; Prova: Professor - Língua Portuguesa)

> Analise o período a seguir.
>
> **"Ele deixou entrar o garçom antes da hora da festa e não o viu esconder alguns talheres de prata, apesar de ser um administrador de experiência"**.
>
> Com relação à estrutura sintática do período acima, assinale a afirmativa correta:
> A) São duas as orações reduzidas do período.
> B) Há apenas uma oração reduzida no período
> C) Os termos "o garçom" e o pronome "o" exercem a mesma função sintática.
> D) "De prata" e "da festa" exercem a função de adjuntos adverbiais.
> E) O período é composto por coordenação e subordinação.

Gostaria de ajuda para definir **quais são as orações coordenadas e subordinadas no período apresentado**.